# Command to "binary images" loaded into a running macOS app

Tags: macos

I'm looking for a macOS command which will list the binary images loaded into a specified running macOS process.  In other words, I want the *Binary Images:* section of a crash report, without the crash.

I want this because several users of my macOS app report that its windows *just don't open*.  This app works fine for 99% of users, and works fine for these users if they run it in a new macOS user account.  Among other things, I would like to see what system hacks may be injecting code into my app.  The command I'm looking for must be available in stock Macs which do not have Apple's Developer Tools installed.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

vmmap seems to work, although it gives somewhat more than I asked for:

`/usr/bin/vmmap -www $pid`

where $pid is the process identifier of the target app's executable.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about a command, but I think the Activity Monitor provides what you're asking.

- Open Activity Monitor
- Select the process you're interested in
- Choose the ellipsis circle (...) to open the System Diagnostics Options menu
- Select Sample process